# how to find out how long visitors stay on my website(duration time)

Tags: express

I'm making a simple analytics admin assuming I'm the owner of a shopping mall as my first project

I've looked up a lot about it but, I couldn't find any information. What I've found out so far is that most existing marketing toole uses cookie and they caclulates it in some ways like they set some cookie with current time and set another cookie when users move to another page on website.

My website is made of AJAX and expressjs with mysql and I'll send user's average duration time to my admin page

Could anyone tell me how to track duration time?

I'm definitely not distributing the idea but it is only for my team prject

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with a combination of `localStorage` (optionally) and `onbeforeunload`.

- Set the current time when a user first gets to site
- Store it in localstorage
- When they are about to leave, `onbeforeunload`, you can save / calculate the duration

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload